# Gmail for programmers

Tags: email, gmail

As a programmer, I really despise any email not written in plain text (MIME type `plain/text`) and not wrapped at 80 chars width.

However the default gmail app only sends the emails I compose as `text/html`.

Is there any way, setting and/or app to get my favourite formatting?

Comment: Since this is titled, "Gmail for Programmers", you could create a small application that provides the correct intent to compose as "text/html".

Answer (score 1):

[Kaiten Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaitenmail.adsupported) lets you send emails in these formats:

- Plain text (images and formatting will be removed)
- HTML (images and formatting are preserved)
- Automatic (plain text unless replying to an HTML message)

I'm not sure about the the width though. I haven't seen any setting where I can set it to 80 (or any other value).

By the way, I sync my GMail and Yahoo mail with Kaiten.

Comment: Sorry for being a necromancer, but I also wanted plain text in Gmail and have been a long time Kaiten user since 2012 ... Kaiten still sucks big time when it comes to searching -- server-side IMAP search is still largely broken in Kaiten, despite it claiming it works. The Gmail app is heaps better in that regard.